# Is $2p_ip_j\lt p_{j+1}^2$ for $i\lt j$?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Initially, I was wondering is the following statement true or not-

> Let $p_k$ be the $k^{\text{th}}$ prime.
> Then, $2p_ip_j\lt p_{j+1}^2$, where $i\le j$

But then I realized that the case $i=j$ has obvious counter-examples like-

$2 \times 5^2 \gt 7^2$

So I excluded the possibility of $i=j$, then the statement becomes

> Let $p_k$ be the $k^{\text{th}}$ prime.
> Then, $2p_ip_j\lt p_{j+1}^2$, where $i\lt j$.

I cannot find any counter-examples for this. So I thought about using [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) which states
$2p_j\gt p_{j+1}$ and the fact that $\frac{p_i}{p_{j+1}}\lt 1$ since $i\lt j+1$.

So, $\frac{p_i}{p_{j+1}}\lt 1$

$\implies -\frac{p_i}{p_{j+1}}>-1$

Multiplying this with the statement of Bertrand's Postulate gives us

$-\frac{2p_ip_j}{p_{j+1}}>-p_{j+1}$

$\implies 2p_ip_j<p_{j+1}^2$

Obviously, we can't just multiply inequalities, especially when dealing with negative numbers and not only that but this line of reasoning also implies the case $i=j$ since $j\lt j+1$ which I just disproved.

To validate my reasoning I was trying to investigate how to multiply inequalities when dealing with negative numbers but that quickly became too complicated for me to work with.

So my question is-

**Is it possible to validate my reasoning so that it works? If not, I would like to have a proof of the statement.**

Comment: $2\times13\times17=442>361=19^2$.

Comment: and indeed it seems $2p_{j-1}^{\,}p_j^{\,} > p_{j+1}^2$ when $p_j \ge 17$

Comment: Trying to flip an inequality by multiplying it with $-1$ is usually of no avail.

Comment: Since $i$ is arbitary (only bounded by $j$), there are plenty of counterexamples. To see that consider that for large $j$ we have $\frac{p_j}{p_{j+1}}\approx 1$, hence it boils basically down to compare $2p_i$ with $p_{j+1}$. $2p_i$ can easily be made smaller or larger than $p_{j+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a few examples before attempting to prove anything.

```
2 x 13 x 17 > 361
2 x 17 x 19 > 529
2 x 19 x 23 > 841
2 x 23 x 29 > 961
2 x 29 x 31 > 1369
2 x 31 x 37 > 1681
2 x 37 x 41 > 1849
2 x 41 x 43 > 2209
2 x 43 x 47 > 2809
2 x 47 x 53 > 3481
2 x 53 x 59 > 3721
2 x 59 x 61 > 4489
2 x 61 x 67 > 5041
2 x 67 x 71 > 5329
2 x 71 x 73 > 6241
2 x 73 x 79 > 6889
2 x 79 x 83 > 7921
```

---

Your attempt to use Bertrand's postulate leads to the opposite direction. **Feel it with your heart!** Bertrand's postulate states the *closeness* of primes -- the next prime will never be further then twice this prime. However, your conjecture states the *apartness* of primes -- twice the product of smaller primes will never reach the square of a bigger prime.

From this, we can conclude that, if you are to prove your conjecture (which you can't, but we can learn from it), Bertrand's postulate will *never*, *ever* help you! It will always push you towards the other direction. Unless..

**Unless**, you come across a situation where an inequality is "flipped" by a constraint. For instance, given $a+b+c + abc = 10$, and suppose you have the inequality $a+b+c > 3$, which states that $a,b,c$ are *big*. Then you can get the inequality $abc < 7$, stating that $a,b,c$ are *small*. This is an example of how inequalities may be "flipped".

Comment: I am stupid forever

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Don't feel that way. Nobody knows that from the beginning.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar If you feel I spoke a little bit too harsh, then I apologize. But in this way, information can be conveyed more efficiently, you know ;)

Comment: . .....thanks